# how do I make a for loop understand that I want it to run i for all values inside x. x being a defined array

Tags: python-3.x

My code right now is as it follows:

```
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

"""
TITLE
"""

def f(x,y):
  for i in range(len(x)):
    y.append(exp(-x[i]) - sin (pi*x[i]/2))

def ddxf(x,y2):
  for i in range(len(x)):
    y2.append(-exp(-x[i]) - (pi/2)*cos(pi*x[i]/2))
  
y = []
y2 = []
f(x, y)  
x = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)

plt.title('Graph of function x')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.plot(x, y, 'g')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

x0 = float(input("Insert the approximate value of the first positive root: "))

intMax = 100
i = 0
epsilon = 1.e-7

while abs(f(x0,y)) > epsilon and i < intMax:
  x1 = x0 - (f(x0))/(ddxf(x0))
  x0 = x1
  i += 1

print (i)
print (x1)
```

I get this error when running the program. it seems that (len(x)) cannot be used if x isnt a string. which doesn't make sense to me. if the array has a len and isn't infinite, why (len(x)) cant read his length? anyway, please help me. hope I made myself clear

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the error: You are using `x` before defining it. In your code, you first use `f(x, y)` and only after that you actually define what `x` is (namely `x = np.linspace(0, 4, 100)`). You probably want to swap these two lines to fix the issue.

Regarding the question in the title: `len(x)` should be fine to get the length of a list. However, in Python you don't need to go through a list like that. You can instead use `for element_name in list_name:` This will essentially go through `list_name` element by element and make it available to you with the name `element_name`.
There is also something called list comprehensions in Python - you might want to take a look at those and see whether you can apply it to your code.

Comment: yeah, i realized that x being after f(x,y) in the code a little bit after I posted the question. But, still, the problem in the title continues. when i enter the input for the first guess in x0 and the program tries to run it through the def f(x,y), it errors. the new error being "type object 'float' has no length

Comment: its kinda hard to explain whats going on via this comment section, as i cant post images down here. so i think ill just close the question already. I know another way of making this code work, but i really wanted to try to solve this problem using y.append. well, guess i cant

Comment: @Toin "it errors. the new error being "type object 'float' has no length" - The issue is that you want a number to behave like a list. Either you have to change how you call f, or what f does. Additionally, in the last loop you call f with one argument, even though you defined it to take two. It isn't really clear what exactly you want to do with f or y.append. You can always edit/update your question (as far as I know, at least) to clarify the issue.